# how change name of vue.js application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I want to share a URL on Facebook (in red on picture), the name is not the one mentioned in the "application-name" meta tag but the one in package.json

Is there a way to fix this?

[!share a URL on Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCVmi.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCVmi.png)

Comment: Update the `package.json`?

Comment: no success with this action, sorry :-(

Comment: Did you changed the <title> in the /index.html file in the root? Did you add any meta property tags on the head of the page?

Comment: in public/index.html, i have this

Comment: <title>ONE TITLE - <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>

Comment: in google i have same issue after link I have name from package.json, not title from tag of index.html

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook and Linkedin when you want to share URL, you have to add the open graph tags to have the right texts and visuals.

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR SITEWEB NAME" />
<meta property="og:description" content="bla-bla." />
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= require('./imagesBlogs/og_image_200x200.png') %>" />
```